# .htaccess HTTP forcing does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website hosted on a shared hosting service and have access to the configuration through **cPanel**.

I want to redirect all *https* requests to *http*, for example:

```
https://www.domain.com/anything_goes_here.hph
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/anything_goes_here.hph
```

I have the following *.htaccess* file in *public_html* folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It's not working, though. No https request is altered, as if the configuration is not active.

I have tried testing the file at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, and it says redirection should occur for *https* requests, but it's not working for my website.

Installed **Apache** version is **2.2.29**.

Please let me know if you need any more details to help me solve the problem. I'm pretty new to website administration, so I don't know what information can be of help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `On` in your `RewriteCond`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: As you suggested, I tried putting garbage text in .htaccess and got 500 errors all around. Apache version is listed in the original question, 2.2.29.

Comment: Just that one. I have `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /` above that, as in original question text.

Comment: When you added garbage text did it give 500 for `https://` request also or only for `http://`?

Comment: Just tried it now, and bingo! 500 error only for http. https is still redirecting me to https://www.knjizaraleda.ba/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi. I've kept the real domain here so you can see the page it's redirecting me to. I'll change the domain to fake on later on. So it seems that .htaccess is working only for http requests? Do you know why is this happening? Note that I have removed the garbage text now, website is live and it needs to be working.

Comment: ok that is great to know, something I have always been suspecting. That means `VirtualHost` entry of your `https` site is using a different `DocumentRoot` than `http` site. You need to make sure both `DocumentRoot` are same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66055/discussion-between-nikola-malesevic-and-anubhava).